# Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() Android Studio Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello im currently building an app using firebase database, im facing an error and i dont know howw to solve this, its say it cant get pass the child key

```
public FirebaseDatabaseHelper() {
    mDataPelanggan = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mReferencePelanggan = mDataPelanggan.getReference("datapelanggan");
}
public void readPelanggan(final DataStatus dataStatus){
    mReferencePelanggan.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            pelanggans.clear();
            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
            for(DataSnapshot keyNode : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                keys.add(keyNode.getKey());
                Pelanggan pelanggan = keyNode.getValue(Pelanggan.class);
                pelanggans.add(pelanggan);

            }
            dataStatus.DataIsLoaded(pelanggans,keys);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}

public void addPelanggan(Pelanggan pelanggan, final DataStatus dataStatus){
    String  key = mReferencePelanggan.push().getKey();
    mReferencePelanggan.child(key).setValue(pelanggan)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    dataStatus.DataIsInserted();
                }
            });

}

public void updatePelanggan(String key, Pelanggan pelanggan, final DataStatus dataStatus){
    mReferencePelanggan.child(key).setValue(pelanggan)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    dataStatus.DataIsUpdated();
                }
            });
}
public void deletePelanggan(String key, final DataStatus dataStatus){
    mReferencePelanggan.child(key).setValue(null)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    dataStatus.DataIsDeleted();
                }
            });
}
```

here is the error im facing

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 6839
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
> at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(DatabaseReference.java:96)
> at com.example.myapplication.FirebaseDatabaseHelper.updatePelanggan(FirebaseDatabaseHelper.java:73)
> at com.example.myapplication.PelangganDetail$1.onClick(PelangganDetail.java:71)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6605)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6582)
> at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25897)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

line 71 which lead to "mReferencePelanggan.child(key).setValue(pelanggan)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67449449/4828650

Answer (score 0):

The error messages is telling you that the `key` you're passing to `child()` is null in the method `updatePelanggan`.  You're going to have to do some debugging to figure out why that is.  You're not showing the call to `updatePelanggan`, so it's not possible to see here where exactly that null value is coming from.

Comment: hello, thanks for answering. already tried debugging but no issue, it occur when i do some update or on update button i did, sorry for not showing where the call to `updatePelanggan` but here it is [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/iTOQFkk)